# How many minimized DFA's possible?

Tags: computation-theory, dfa

How many minimized DFA's are possible with states {A,B} over alphabet={a,b}? I have worked out this question and obtained 122 as answer. I took two cases 
1. Minimal DFA with 2 states
2. Minimal DFA with 1 state

In case 1 all 4 cases of A and B that is each of being final, one final and one non-final and both non-final. So total is 120

In case 2 two single state DFA's.

Hope my problem is clear. Is this the correct answer. If no, answer with explanation is appreciated.

Comment: I understand your question but I'm not clear on where you arrived at the number 120 for possible DFAs.

Comment: It depends on whether you count isomorphic DFAs several times. For example, the one-state DFAs can use state A or state B. Do you only count them once? Also for two states there are isomorphic automata. Probably they come in isomorphic pairs with two states except for "symmetric" ones where the isomorphism would be the ideniity.

Answer (score 3):

(The below assumes we're talking about complete DFAs - that is, DFAs in which every possible transition is defined to and from well-defined states. This is in contrast with incomplete DFAs that might be missing transitions.)

An important clarification: Not all two-state DFAs are minimal.

- For example, any two-state DFA without an accepting state is equivalent to a single-state DFA without an accepting state, with every transition going to and from the single state.
- If you end up with a two-state DFA in which no transitions leave the starting state, this is not a minimal DFA.
- If both states are accepting, then the DFA is equivalent to a single-state DFA which accepts every string.

Your analysis of single-state DFAs is correct. There are two: the DFA that accepts all strings over the alphabet, and the DFA that accepts no strings over the alphabet.

For two-state DFAs, each state can be either an accepting state or not. There are 4 such configurations. Two of them are not minimal, by the above observations.

Transitions have these properties:

- Each transition has a starting state, a destination state and a letter from the alphabet.
- Each state has two transitions (one for each letter in {a,b}).
- Each transition has two possible destinations (A or B).

Number of transitions in a two-state DFA = number of states * size of alphabet  = `2 * 2 = 4` Each transition comes in a pair (e.g., for transition {A,a} -> x, x can be only A or B). There are 4 such pairs, each with a binary choice, for a total of 16 transition configurations (`2^4 = 16`).

There are 2 valid minimal configurations of accepting states (A accepts, B does not; B accepts, A does not).

So the maximum value of possible minimal two-state DFAs is `2 * 16 = 32`. And some of those DFAs will not be minimal. 32 is an upper bound.

There are at least 8 of those that are not minimal. These correspond to the 8 two-state DFAs where the transitions from the starting state end in the starting state.

So 24 is a tighter upper bound, and I believe this is the minimal number of two-state DFAs.

Another way to approach this (and how I found my own error) is to consider the structure of minimal two-state DFAs. Each has two states which can be in two configurations (A accepting, or B accepting, but not both or neither), a multiplier of 2. The A (starting) state has to have one transition from A to B (with two choices of character (a or b), or two transitions from A to B, a multiplier of 3. The B state doesn't have restrictions on its transitions, so it has a total of 4 possible transitions, a multiplier of 4. Now check that `2 * 3 * 4 = 24` to confirm the above analysis.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate explanation!!

Comment: @Midhun: I had made a mistake in my calculations. I've updated it with a new calculation and I'm much more confident in that answer.

Comment: 24 is with two states so together with dfa of one state, that is 2 configurations, will be 26 right?

Comment: Aren't there two more one-state DFAs? The ones for a^* and for b^*.

Comment: @PeterLeupold: Take `a*` for example. It, as an NFA, has one state (an accepting state), with one transition on `a` to itself. As a DFA, this has two states: an accepting state and a non-accepting state. On `b`, there is a transition from the accepting state to the non-accepting state. DFAs need all transitions and all states to be complete, unlike NFAs.

Comment: No,@Welbog, what your are talking about here is the completeness of automata. A one-state automaton with a loop for a i perfectly deterministic and thus a DFA. Non-determinism means two transitions reading the same symbol leaving the same state - with one state that is not even possible unless you allow multiple copies of the same transition.  A different question is whether the definition of minimality includes the requirement of completeness. This is often so but not clear from the OP. If completeness is required there is indeed no minimal one-state automaton for a^* over the alphabet{a,b}.

Comment: @PeterLeupold: Fair callout. To me it seemed clear from the assertion that there are only two one-state DFAs from the OP that he's talking about complete DFAs. But if not, my answer is not valid. I will clarify.